# Windows Batch: Read a very long line from unformatted xml

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I use a batch file to read a very long line of unformatted xml? I'm trying to insert a line break after every ">".

The problem is, that my batch file skips to the next line after it finds a ">".

And because of this behaviour only the first tag of my xml file is displayed (there's only one line, a second line does not exist).

This is the command that I've used:

```
FOR /F "delims=>" %%i IN (test.xml) DO @echo %%i
```

This is an example of how my xml file looks:

```
<simpleType name="parseType"><restriction base="xs:token"><enumeration value="xml"/<enumeration value="text"/></restriction></simpleType>
```

This is the output of the cmd command:

```
<simpleType name="parseType"
```

Comment: sorry what exactly u want? if U want to load file into console, U can use "MORE" command not "FOR", if you want to load XML line by line - much ease to write simple console app that simply do

Comment: My XML file has only one line. This is because the line breaks are missing. I want to format it with a batch file, but the line is to long to read it completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a robust way of doing it and handles very long lines:

```
type "file.txt" | repl ">" ">\r\n" XL >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there no other way without using helper files?

Comment: It depends on how long your lines are.  Plain Batch has limitations and is not as robust, or as simple, as the helper batch file above.

Comment: about 50000 characters

Comment: Plain batch is limited to `8191` characters in a line.  `repl.bat` uses native Windows scripting and can handle your file fine.

Answer (score 0):

sorry what exactly u want?

if U want to load file into console, U can use "MORE" command instead of "FOR".

```
more %%1
```

if you want to load XML line by line - much ease to write simple console app that simply do:

```
Console.WriteLine(XElement.Load(args[0]));
```

So it will be validly formatted.

And you can use it in "BAT"

If you want to read XML "line-by-line" but without any line breakers - it's strange idea, but you still can download Unix utils for Windows and use grep and so on but it will be brain crash for you and nothing more.