# Split one file into multiple based on keyword

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to split my single file into two file when a particular keyword comes in the file.. Consider that I have whole content in single line. So it is not possible to count line number and then split it.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: And where is the problem in your code?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25890046/2152082) could be helpful

Comment: I have not written any code for this yet. For example if  I have a file content like "This is my file content and I want to split file from here Content should be split to other file" . Not two separate file from keyword "from here"

Comment: How long is the line in your file? `cmd` variables are limited to 8191 chars. If your line may be longer, your native `cmd` options are limited.

Comment: Can you past the contents of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Read the line from the file
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do set "line=%%a"

rem Split the line at "from here " string
set "part1=%line:from here =from here" & set "part2=%"

rem Create the two output files
> output1.txt echo %part1%
> output2.txt echo %part2%
```

input.txt:

```
This is my file content and I want to split file from here Content should be split to other file
```

output1.txt:

```
This is my file content and I want to split file from here
```

output2.txt:

```
Content should be split to other file
```

This method can only read a maximum of 8191 characters from input file; it also fail if the input file contain special Batch characters.

If you want a more precise answer, please post a more precise question...